# Trouble upgrading Blazor Server site 5 to 6

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I did:

1. Create new 6.0 project
2. Copy all components and code etc. to new project
3. Add my services that used to be in `Startup.cs` to `Program.cs`
4. Move my global usings to a new file, `Globals.cs`

The code compiles and begins to run, but never shows anything before it explodes.

**The problem**

In `_Host.cshtml`, the last line now throws a null reference error:

```
@page "/"
@namespace BEC.web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

I know this question is hard to answer, but I'm wondering if anyone can shed a little light on where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: Any particular reason you moved services from Startup to Program?

Comment: The exception is probably inside the `App` component itself and not in the `_Host.cshtml`. Please post your stack trace if you could and enable detailed exceptions in the BlazorServer config.

Comment: @Mayur Ekbote  Yes, I want to conform to the default 6.0 app as closely as possible, so I can understand how they streamlined it.

Comment: @HMZ The app and the services run fine, but something in the pages is causing the App to blow up.  I've decided to refactor the whole site anyway, though.  There was some organizational inconsistencies and so on, and playing Satisfactory has made me interested in clean organization. :)

Answer (score 1):

Define "Explodes".

My guess is its in one of the components being loaded in the "/" route.  There are a few problems in error reporting that have been introduced in Net6 when, as you put it, your app explodes. See for example - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38380.

Try creating a minimal App and see what happens - no router, just some plain html output. See what happens.  Then add the router, but with fixed content to see if the router is OK.  I've added some code below to show you the sort of stuff to try.

```
@*<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
    <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
    </Router>
*@
@* Step 1*@
Hello World

@* Step 2*@
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        Found
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        Not Found
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@* Step 3*@
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <StackOverflow.Server.Pages.Index />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        Not Found
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: The stack trace in your link, and where you got the error, looks suspiciously similar to my definition of "explodes."  So does this mean that I've just copied in my old "/" page together with the default Index page that also has `page "/"`?

Comment: __Update__  Thanks to that, I've got the page to run.  I think there's a lot of cleaning up to do still, but at least I'm getting a page now.  I have to say, my excitement about Blazor 6 is not quite as keen as it was a couple days ago-- that error is unforgivable, and Intellisense seems to be even worse than before.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you necessarily had a duplicate route, but to shown you there are obviously some Net6 issues in error reporting on startup.  My impressions are the similar to yours.   Intellisense seems to go missing most of the time in Razor files, and wrongly corrects you,  I might post a question here to see what other people are seeing.